# Definiteness of function $Q(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 - 6 \cdot x_1 \cdot x_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I am currently struggling with a simple quadratic form:

$$Q(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 - 6 \cdot x_1 \cdot x_2$$

It is obvious by completing the square (or by simply look at 3D-graph), that this function is **indefinite**:

$$Q(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 - 3 \cdot x_2)^2 - 9 \cdot x_2^2$$

Now I want to the exact same analysis with the square matrix A:

$$\mathbf{x}^\top A \mathbf{x}$$

for $A$ I get the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  -6 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

If I analyse the matrix with Sylvester criterion (simply by adding row II + 6 * row I) I get the eigenvalues 1 and 0. This means that the matrix is **pos. semi-definite**?

The matrix is also positive definite, if I apply the Hurwitz criterion to the matrix:

$$k=1: 1 ≥ 0, 0 ≥ 0$$
$$k=2: 1 * 0 - (-6) * 0 ≥ 0$$

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the analysis yield the same outcome?

Comment: Edit: Could it be that the square matrix should be symmetric and only then is the matrix analysis possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $A$ is matrix representation of $Q(x_1,x_2)$, if so, then your matrix is wrong. Check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367923/is-there-a-systematic-way-of-finding-the-matrix-of-a-quadratic-form#:%7E:text=The%20matrix%20of%20the%20quadratic,b2b2c). So $A$ should instead be: \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -3 \\
  -3 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Now using Sylvester criterion you could easily prove what you're looking for.